# Changing Chart Number Labels to Text not working (iOS Charts)

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I'm plotting sunrise/sunset against time, so time goes along the X axis with iOS Charts (Daniel Gindi).
If I display the x labels as numbers they manifest correctly: If I swap them over to text (Jan - Dec) only Jan shows up???

[image]

Associated iOS Chart code:

```
    // Setup X Axis
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = 366
    lineChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 30
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 12
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisLineWidth = 2
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = .black
    lineChartView.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
```

If I swap it over to literals then I only get Jan. All the values are populated. Any ideas?

[image]

Code: (n.b. putting labelCount before IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months) makes no difference.)

```
     // Setup X Axis
    let months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = 366
    lineChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 30
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 12
    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months)
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisLineWidth = 2
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = .black
    lineChartView.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
```

Comment: It would appear that this issue has been going on for years and originated in the Android code that iOS Charts mirrors. There are a lot of work arounds on the web, rather than the Framework being corrected :-(. Almost all require using "IAxisValueFormatter". But when I declare this in, say, "class ChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {" I get the error "Cannot find type 'IAxisValueFormatter' in scope". Any ideas?

Comment: did you import Charts in the class?

Comment: Presume you mean as in: "import UIKit
import Charts"? Yes

Comment: that weird, i never had the same issue when use IAxisValueFormatter